# Calculate partial integral and result is incorrect. Finding my incorrect step.

Tags: integration, solution-verification

I want to calculate $\int 50 e^{130t} \sin(60 t) dt$ with partial integral as follows:

\begin{align*}
 \int 50 e^{130t} \sin(60 t) dt &= 50 \int   \sin(60 t) e^{130t} dt\\
 &= 50\left[ \sin(60 t) \dfrac{1}{130} e^{130t} - \int \dfrac{1}{130} e^{130t} 60\cos (60t)dt\right]\\
 &= \dfrac{5}{13} \sin(60 t)  e^{130t} - \dfrac{300}{13} \int \cos (60t) e^{130t} dt\\
 &= \dfrac{5}{13} \sin(60 t)  e^{130t} - \dfrac{300}{13} \left[ \cos (60t) \dfrac{1}{130} e^{130t}- \int \dfrac{1}{130} e^{130t} (-60\sin (60t))dt\right] \\
 &= \dfrac{5}{13} \sin(60 t)  e^{130t} -  \dfrac{30}{169} \cos (60t)  e^{130t}- \dfrac{1800}{169} \int  e^{130t} \sin (60t)dt
\end{align*}
\begin{align*}
 \left(50+ \dfrac{1800}{169}\right)\int  e^{130t} \sin(60 t) dt &= \dfrac{5}{13} \sin(60 t)  e^{130t} -  \dfrac{30}{169} \cos (60t)  e^{130t}\\
 &= \dfrac{\dfrac{5}{13} \sin(60 t)  e^{130t} -  \dfrac{30}{169} \cos (60t)  e^{130t}}{\dfrac{10250}{169}}+C\\
 &= \dfrac{13}{2050} \sin(60 t)  e^{130t} -  \dfrac{3}{1025} \cos (60t)  e^{130t} +C
\end{align*}

I try to check with maple and the result is
\begin{align*}
 -\dfrac{6}{41}\cos(60t) e^{130t} +\dfrac{13}{41} e^{130t} \sin (60t) +C.
\end{align*}

I spent many time to check my answer, and I cannot find where my step is wrong.
Which step is incorrect?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything you wrote up to this step is correct:

$$\left(50 + \frac{1800}{169}\right) \int e^{130t} \sin 60t \, dt = \frac{5}{13} e^{130t} \sin 60t - \frac{30}{169} e^{130t} \cos 60t.$$
but the original integral is $$\int \color{red}{50} e^{130t} \sin 60t \, dt.$$  So you need to divide both sides by $1 + \frac{36}{169}$, not $50 + \frac{1800}{169}$.  As a result, your answer is off by a factor of $50$.

In order to avoid such confusion, and make the calculation easier, we can write
$$I(a,b) = \int e^{at} \sin bt \, dt,$$ and with the substitution $u = bt$, $du = b \, dt$, we get
$$I(a,b) = \frac{1}{b} \int e^{(a/b) u} \sin u \, du.$$  So letting $c = a/b$,
$$\begin{align}
b I(a,b) &= \int e^{cu} \sin u \, du \\
&= \frac{1}{c} e^{cu} \sin u - \frac{1}{c} \int e^{cu} \cos u \, du \\
&= \frac{1}{c} e^{cu} \sin u - \frac{1}{c} \left( \frac{1}{c} e^{cu} \cos u + \frac{1}{c} \int e^{cu} \sin u \, du \right) \\
&= \frac{1}{c} e^{cu} \sin u - \frac{1}{c^2} e^{cu} \cos u - \frac{1}{c^2} b I(a,b).
\end{align}$$
Hence
$$b c^2 I(a,b) = c e^{cu} \sin u - e^{cu} \cos u + b I(a,b)$$
and
$$I(a,b) = \frac{e^{cu} (c \sin u - \cos u)}{b(1+c^2)} = \frac{e^{at} (a \sin bt - b \cos bt)}{a^2 + b^2}.$$

Then your integral is simply $50 I(130, 60)$.